# Function to load correct CSS for Template not working

Tags: page-template, wp-enqueue-style

I have three templates I want to be able to use (Index Page, Main Template, and Default). I was able to add a "if/else" statement into a function to get the correct CSS file to load depending on which template was being used between two templates (Index and Default).

However, when I try to use "elseif" so I can add in another option for Main Template, it doesn't work. Instead the page that uses Main Template loads the Index Page CSS.

This is the code in question:

```
    if ( is_page() && ! is_page_template( 'page-templates/index_page.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style1', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/index_page.css' );
    } elseif ( is_page() && ! is_page_template( 'page-templates/main_template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style2', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/main_template.css' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style3', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/content-sidebar.css' );
    }
```

Here's the whole function:

```
function authorluncheon_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'authorluncheon-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    if ( is_page() && ! is_page_template('page-templates/index_page.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style1', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/index_page.css' );
    } elseif ( is_page() && ! is_page_template( 'page-templates/main_template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style2', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/main_template.css' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'authorLuncheon-layout-style3', get_template_directory_uri().'/layouts/content-sidebar.css' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'authorluncheon-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'authorluncheon-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'authorluncheon_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your big problem here is your use of underscores (`_`) in your page template names. According to the [**Handbook of Coding Standards**](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions)

> Files should be named descriptively using lowercase letters. **Hyphens** should separate words.
>
> - my-plugin-name.php

Also, for best practices you should call your custom page templates *page-whatever.php*

So for instance, *index_page.php* should be renamed to *page-index.php* and *index_page.css* should be renamed to something like *index-style.css*

**NOTE:** Just one think to remember, if you are talking about your homepage which uses index.php or a blog page that uses index.php or home.php, you should use `is_home()` instead of `is_page() && !is_page_template('page-templates/index_page.php')`. If you have set a static front page, you should use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_page() && !is_page_template('page-templates/index_page.php')`. Your front page should also be named *front-page.php* for good practice, although you can use other names as set out [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

I would think that this will solve your problem. If not, let me know

**EDIT**

```
 if (is_page() && !is_page_template('page-templates/index_page.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('authorLuncheon-layout-style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/index_page.css');
    } elseif (is_page() && !is_page_template('page-templates/main_template.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('authorLuncheon-layout-style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/main_template.css');
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('authorLuncheon-layout-style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/content-sidebar.css');
    }
```

Read your code above in normal English

> if( a page is displayed and the template is NOT page-templates/index_page.php) {
>
> enqueue my style authorLuncheon-layout-style1
>
> } else if( a page is displayed and the template is NOT page-templates/main_template.php) {
>
> enqueue my style authorLuncheon-layout-style2
>
> } else {
>
> when the template displayed IS page-templates/main_template.php or page-templates/index_page.php {
>
> enqueue my style authorLuncheon-layout-style3
>
> }

So this is basically a wrong use of operators. Remember `!` means the opposite of the conditional it is attached to. So you should rearrange your code completely for this to work. This is just a rough draught

```
if ( is_page() && is_page_template( 'page-templates/index_page.php' ) ) {
        //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON THIS SPECIFIC PAGE 
    } elseif ( is_page() && is_page_template( 'page-templates/main_template.php' ) ) {
       //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON THIS SPECIFIC PAGE
    } else {
       //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON ANY OTHER PAGE
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

You can also try this. I would also not use the `is_page()`

```
if ( !is_page_template( 'page-templates/index_page.php' ) && !is_page_template( 'page-templates/main_template.php' ) ) {
       //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON ANY OTHER PAGE THAN THIS TWO
    } elseif ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/index_page.php' ) ) {
        //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON THIS SPECIFIC PAGE 
    } elseif ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/main_template.php' ) ) {
       //enqueue whatever style you want to use ON THIS SPECIFIC PAGE
    }
```

Comment: I renamed the files but unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: I'm quickly busy with a long edit on my answer. Realized something else

Comment: I understand that it shouldn't work the way I have it set up with the "!", and originally I had it set up like you suggested in your edit, but for some reason it breaks and changes everything to the default CSS file (the third option) instead of the correct ones. I tried it again just to make sure, with the newly renamed files, and I get the same result

Comment: What happens if you remove `is_page() && `

Comment: I tried edit 2, both with and without is_page() &&, but it said "Warning: Division by zero" and referred to the first line of your edit. The page loaded below the warning error, but showed no change from before

Comment: Crap, syntax error, sorry, see update

Comment: I fixed the syntax, but both specified templates load up the default CSS file instead of the correct ones now

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, the code in my edit 2 works. `ìs_page_template()` is correct. Try your code in one of the bundled themes, clear all caches, and also check that `wp_head()` is called in in the proper position, that is before the closing head (`</head>`) tag

Comment: I'm not sure why this happened, but I installed the new WordPress update today and suddenly everything worked fine. So I'll give you the answer credit since I'm using your streamlined code, but I'm not really sure what ended up solving it. Thanks for all the time you took helping me!

Comment: It's my pleasure, I think this was also your problem in your previous question. Strange that your core files got corrupted. This was going to be my last resort to ask you to reinstall wordpress